# Why is a tuple with length=2 described as an 'int object' and therefore not iterable

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have asked the question of ChatGPT, in Neeva, Google & here. On SO there are a lot of similar questions but I can't relate any of them to my example.

Small example that hopefully illustrates my problem:

```
import numpy as np

# Small function that returns an array of values
def npArrayReturn(index, numbers):
    
    results = np.array
    results = numbers * index
      
    return results

# Code that calls the function to return modified values - logical steps & print statements that ends with the problem  
# Return one set of modified values
i = 2 
smalls = np.array([1,2,3])
bigs = np.array
bigs = npArrayReturn(i,smalls)
print("The returned array is:",bigs)

# Return multiple sets of modified values
indexResults = [],[]
print("indexResults is type:",type(indexResults))
print("The length of indexResults is:",len(indexResults))

# Why is a tuple with length=2 described as an 'int object' and therefore not iterable
for i in len(indexResults):
    indexResults[i] = npArrayReturn(i,smalls)
```

Output

```
The returned array is: [2 4 6]
indexResults is type: <class 'tuple'>
The length of indexResults is: 2
```

snip ----><------

```
line 27, in <module>
    for i in len(indexResults):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

In my 'real' code I am trying to store `numpy` arrays representing text in an array of arrays. I then want to access each `numpy` array as I process the contents.

BTW ChatGPT finishes its answer with this:
"In any case, a tuple with length=2 (or any length greater than 1) is certainly iterable. You can loop over its elements using a for loop, access individual elements using indexing (e.g., my_tuple[0] to access the first element), and perform other operations on it just like any other iterable object in Python."

Comment: `len(indexResults)` is not a tuple.

Comment: Oh! You mean I have missed `range`? I see now.

Comment: Unrelated, but what was your intention with `results = np.array` and `bigs = np.array`? Since you redefine `results` and `big` in the next line, those are useless.

Comment: Ah, on second read it's more obvious what you're doing. `for...in`  needs to be given an iterable on the right. `range` is the basic way of turning a number into a range of numbers from 0 to that number, which corresponds with indices if the number is the length of a sequence.

Comment: Yes missing range in `for i in range (len(indexResults)):` was dumb. It changes the error to `'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `for i in range(len(indexResults)):` in the loop since you are trying to iterate over the results with indices. it would still have errors because you are changing values of a tuple that is immutable.
you should define `indexResults` as a list in this manner:

`indexResults = [[], []]`

Answer (score 2):

let's simplify to see what you're actually doing.

```
length_of_list = len(indexResult) # len_of_list = 2
for i in length_of_list: # for i in 2
    indexResults[i] = npArrayReturn(i,smalls)
```

2 is not a list. 2 is an integer. I'm guessing what you want is:

```
for i in range(length_of_list): # for i in [0, 1]
    ...

# or
for i in range(len(indexResult)): # for i in [0, 1]
    ...
```